# Why can't PostgreSQL performparallel DML?

Tags: postgresql

Currently I find some functions in our project which opens multiple SPIs to insert into or delete from a table, and I think they are wrong. However, the functions seem to work fine in the past, which lead me to this question.

According to some information I gathered from internet, it seems to be safe when multiple workers updating data on different parts of table concurrently, or inserting data without demanding order.

However, I find that PostgreSQL currently just disable parallel on any DML statement. I'm not sure what is the reason behind it. Will parallel DML cause dead locks? or Under what condition would it be safe to open parallel?

Comment: What do you consider parallel DML? A single DML statement running with multiple threads/processes? Or multiple DML statements running against the same table at the same time?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Both. The first is like the typical "insert...select" command, where only the select part can be parallelized. And the second is like opening multiple SPIs in a user-defined function. Both are not supported by PG now.

Comment: For the first one, the answer to "why?" is quite simple: because no one implemented it so far. Most likely it's also the answer to the second one.